# Endpoint for getting scheduled post of an fb page with Graph api

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, schedule, graph-api-explorer

I am using graph API to get a scheduled post from an FB page with graph explorer

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.7/scheduled-post

as listed on this URL by FB. but I'm getting a response as

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "(#803) Some of the aliases you requested do not exist: ...",
    "type": "OAuthException",
    "code": 803,
    "fbtrace_id": "BR5TIj6pchf"
  }
}
```

please, friends, let me know what should I use here field name instead of `{fieldname_of_type_ScheduledPost}`

Comment: did you manage to get scheduled posts?

Comment: I got the same error. I uploaded 2 scheduler post, but how can I get by graph API?

Comment: you need to provide an example of the URL called for the request, we cannot debug with such limited information